# PHP / Regex / JavaScript to replace specific word in paths conditionally

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am developing a site using WordPress & phpBB and as you must be aware that the image paths are generated by these CMSs. What I want is............ to hold the output before sending to browser.............. Make changes to image path depending on the device type and finally output the correct images.

**Why do I want to replace the paths?**

Because my NORMAL image is 180KB, my MEDIUM image is 90KB an my SMALL image is 30KB and like this have about 20 images on each page and imagine the amount of page speed I will reduce by replacing it with a smaller image for small and slow devices. Also images are cropped to highlight only the important portion for smaller devices hence changing the dimensions will not resolve my issue.

*I am also not looking for CSS3 Media Queries as I have a specific reason for not using them.*

**What will work for me?**

As my priority is to keep the page load times to minimal, the best solution would be using some **Regular-Expression** as I am not using any JavaScript Libraries in my Template.

If this cannot be achieved without JavaScript, then I would prefer plain old JavaScript method without using any libraries as this will be the only JavaScript function in my template and it would not make any sense to load an entire library for it.

The following is what I was thing should be the approach. However I dont know how to get it. Kindly help.

**Please Note:-** I am very new to PHP and also ZERO at Regex and JavaScript. Hence please explain in a bit detail.

```
<?php ob_start (); ?> /* Start Buffering */


<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pellentesque vestibulum fringilla. Nullam eget fermentum neque. Quisque ullamcorper fringilla quam, eu elementum nisl ornare vitae.</p>
<img src="images/desktop/pic1.jpg"/>
<img src="images/desktop/pic2.jpg"/>
<img src="images/desktop/pic3.jpg"/>
</div>

<?php ob_get_contents();  /* Get the Buffer */

if ($layout = 'mobile') {

    /* replace <img src="images/desktop/pic1.jpg"/> with <img src="images/mobile/pic1.jpg"/>
    /* replace <img src="images/desktop/pic2.jpg"/> with <img src="images/mobile/pic2.jpg"/>
    /* replace <img src="images/desktop/pic3.jpg"/> with <img src="images/mobile/pic3.jpg"/>
    The Folder-Name 'desktop' should be replaced by 'mobile'
    */

} else if ($layout = 'tablet') {

    /* replace <img src="images/desktop/pic1.jpg"/> with <img src="images/tablet/pic1.jpg"/>
    /* replace <img src="images/desktop/pic2.jpg"/> with <img src="images/tablet/pic2.jpg"/>
    /* replace <img src="images/desktop/pic3.jpg"/> with <img src="images/tablet/pic3.jpg"/>
    The Folder-Name 'desktop' should be replaced by 'tablet'
    */

}

ob_end_flush (); /* Send Output to the browser */
?>
```

The values of $layout are being calculated by another PHP Function.

Please feel free to suggest a totally different solution also if you feel that would be a better approach.

Comment: `if ($layout = 'mobile')`: `=` `!=` `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wanting to replace the word "desktop" in your paths to "mobile" or "tablet". You don't need a regular expression.

I *was* going to suggest using `str_replace`, but then I realized you don't need even that.

Try this on for size:

```
<?php ob_start (); ?> /* Start Buffering */
<div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pellentesque vestibulum fringilla. Nullam eget fermentum neque. Quisque ullamcorper fringilla quam, eu elementum nisl ornare vitae.
    </p>
    <img src="images/<?=($layout !== 'desktop' ? $layout : 'desktop')?>/pic1.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/<?=($layout !== 'desktop' ? $layout : 'desktop')?>/pic2.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/<?=($layout !== 'desktop' ? $layout : 'desktop')?>/pic3.jpg"/>
</div>
?>
```

---

What's weird is that *if* layout is always set (that is, 'desktop' normally, or either 'mobile' or 'tablet'), why do you even need to do a replacement of the url? You could just dynamically construct the url like so:

```
<img src="images/<?=$layout?>/pic1.jpg"/>
```

Comment: I do not have any control on the image paths as they are dynamically generated by the CMS. I want to capture the final output of the CMS and make changes in that. Can you please suggest it this way?

Comment: In that case, `str_replace('desktop', $layout, ob_get_contents());`, perhaps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help. Could you please tell me the complete syntax along with some example as I mentioned, I am very new to programming and just learning the game. Please help.

Comment: `$output = ob_get_contents()` should shove everything captured by the output buffer into the variable of your choice. Simply do a string replace (hint: use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)) to change the word "desktop" to whatever is in the variable `$layout`. At that point, `$output` should contain the proper URLs. Echo as necessary.

Comment: Sorry still not clear. Can you please edit your above example to proper code snippet please.

Comment: $output = str_replace('desktop', $layout, ob_get_contents());

Comment: Vikram, it's become apparent after all this that you are trying to alter page content *after* it has already been rendered on the page by your CMS. All the answers here assume you have the output HTML on the server-side available for manipulation. In that case, try using `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` to grab the image assets, and iterate through them to change their `src` attribute.